# How to remove number prefix from file name in a directory?

Tags: shell

I have some mp3 files in a directory. They are in the following formats

1. 9989923_songname.mp3
2. songname012.mp3
3. 898887888.mp3
4. 1. songname.mp3
5. 4_songname.mp3

I need to write a shell script to rename the files in "Audio" directory in to following format

1. 9989923_songname.mp3    ->  songname.mp3
2. songname012.mp3         ->  songname1.mp3  (a series if many files with the same name   exists)
3. 898887888.mp3           ->  unknown1.mp3 (a series if all the characters number)
4. 1. mysongname.mp3     ->  mysongname.mp3
5. 4_yoursongname.mp3      ->  yoursongname.mp3

If duplicate name is there then it will make it to a series with suffix sequence number.
Please help me to write this script. (appreciate if you can explain the solution)

Comment: _Please help me to write this script._: Shouldn't that be __write it for me__ instead?

Answer (score -1):

Here I have created a method which will take the directory name as first argument and the string to be removed from the file name.

```
    private static void RemovePrefixRecursively(string dirName, string prefix)
    {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
                foreach (var file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    var fileName = file.Name;
                    var fileExtention = file.Extension.TrimStart('.');
                    fileName = fileName.Replace("." , string.Empty);
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtention))                fileName = fileName.Replace(fileExtention, string.Empty);
                    System.IO.File.Move(file.FullName, string.Format("{0}\\{1}.{2}", dirName, fileName.Replace(prefix, string.Empty), fileExtention));
                }
                foreach (var dir in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    RemovePrefixRecursively(dir.FullName,prefix);
                }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a shell script.